# fourier transform with an irregular sampling rate

Tags: python, signals, fft

I have some data measured at a sampling rate of 100 samples per second, for example

```
a = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 3, 2, 7, 1, 6]
```

this data represents the vibrations of a car (displacement) as it drives a long, lets say I want to only look at the vibrations when its driving at a certain speed, so after I sample this (maybe by setting the useless values to 0) I get something like

```
b = [1, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0, 1, 6]
```

now if I want to look at the fourier transform data of this data, what do I use as the domain and sample rate?

Do I use

```
b = [1, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0, 1, 6]
```

with the sampling rate 1/100 as before?

Or do I remove the other values

```
c = [1, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 6]
```

and a different sample rate?

Comment: to focus on only keeping data captured during good road speeds put that stretch of good samples into a "window" and send it into your fft call ... skip over samples with bad road speed then repeat when you have encountered another stretch of good speed samples ... this also solves your sample rate question

Comment: If your Question has been answered, this site works that Questioner accepts an Answer that fulfilled his question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think you confuse what sampling rate is.** Sampling rate is generated by your sensor. Without constant sampling rate you cannot calculate correct frequencies. Songs and microphone has standard sampling frequency 44kHz. It doesnt change. Its standard.

What is standard way of calculating frequency spectrum is to cut your signal into time chunks and do spectral analysis on these chunks. Exactly same way as it is done with Tone tuner for guitars.

So, you have sampling frequency `fs = 100hz`. Lets say your chunk will be `0.5s` -> that means your chunk will have `fs*0.5s = 50` values. You will do spectral analysis on these chunks instead of on the whole time_signal

So with this attitude, you can filter chunks that are interesting for you -> above particular speed of car.

Example in code:

```
all_data = [1,2,8,1,2,6,4,7,8,1,3.........] 
chunks = [[1,2,8...],[4,5,7,8,],...]
>>>len(chunks[0])
50
interesting_chunks = chunks that were measured when car reached 40mph
for interesting_chunk in interesting_chunks:
    FFT = np.fft(interesting_chunk)
```

**In a simple way:**

**You CANNOT cut values in pure signal, but if you group signal in chunks, you can cut those chunks and take only those that interest you**

You can ofcourse have just one chunk - exactly covering the period when the car reached your speed. But remember, you cant connect together separate pieces of signal. Chunk need to be continous, not sticked together from here and there

---

**Note** that bigger the chunk, more accurate is the FFT, but bigger is the time window.
Smaller the chunk, less accurate FFT, but you have small time window - good for realtime applications

Comment: great, thank you, so if I seperate the data into chunks, and choose only the chunks for one speed, can I then put those chunks together into one chunk, and fft that?

Comment: this seems like it would be ok to me, since it would be the same as getting the signal just as if the car was driving at that speed the whole time

Comment: @StephenJ You can try to put it together as one chunk, but I am not sure of the result. The problem is that each chunk starts somehow and ends somehow. If you connect those chunks into one chunk, maybe you will confuse the FFT. by the uncontinuous waves. I dont know. Try it and tell me. I am quite interested about the result. But I think it will not work

Comment: @StephenJ After some contemplation I think it wont work at all actually. I would keep it in chunks. You can put togther only those chunks that are next to each other -> because they are continous. But you cant connect chunks that doesnt follow, that are not so-called 'neighbours'

Comment: It seems to give me reasonable looking results, do you think that because the fft is just an implementation of the discrete transform that it discritises the domain anyway, and so the jumps don't matter?

Comment: @StephenJ I dont know for now. When I get home I will test it. Did you try to connect chuncks that are from different 'place'?

Comment: yes, different times, but at the same car speed so the vibrations are at least at a similar order of magnitude, so the discontinuities are small

Comment: @StephenJ So I tested it and its OK to Shuffle consecutivness of CHUNKS. But you cant shuffle or remove a single value inside the CHUNK.

Comment: This is the conclusion I have come to as well, but I think I am actually going to go for your original idea to do the fourier transform for each chunk, and then average over each frequency. Which is working much better

Answer (score 0):

It's not so easy to tell with this few information, but i'll try to guess from my experience:
you can't just drop out the values you are not interested in like that. You are trying to transform a time signal in the frequencies domain and in this way, I think you are altering the physics if the test. What you want to do is to remove the frequencies content of the signal corresponding to a certains speeds.
I would try to use a lowpass filter instead of removing or setting to 0 the values that you don't want. In this way, you can keep the same sampling rate and you are artificially modifying your test's data.
Vibration frequencies should be somehow related to driving speed (guessing higher frequencies for higher speed).

Hope this can be of any help

Ciao